# View directory compilation time difference between asp.net mvc and asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

im extremely curious about exceptional situation between asp.net mvc (4.7.2) and asp.net core mvc (2.2).

What im doing is:

> Create empty asp.net mvc project , add new "TestController" cloned from default "HomeController" , duplicate views of home controller and name View directory as "Test".
>
> doing exactly the same on asp.net core mvc project.
>
> run asp.net mvc project and change url as /Test/Index (the view is exactly the same as Home/Index) and it took ~300ms to run on first time. if i refresh the page it took ~5-6 milliseconds to run.
>
> im doing exactly the same on asp.net core mvc project and it took ~30 ms on first run and ~5-6 ms on every time i refresh.

i tested several cases and i think its all about "First creation of X type of controller".

im working on asp.net on 5-6 years but i've noticed this now. you can say it's no problem just 300 ms , but on the low resourced machine it took ~30 seconds.

what is this all about and how can i reduce this time to asp.net core time (~30ms) ?

**EDIT:**
it turns out its not about the creation of controller. It's about the directories of views. I changed the Index action of TestController's view path with "~/Views/Home/Index" it opened fast (if i rendered any view from this folder before) , but if i **"first time render a view from X directory (or sub directory) it works slowly as i mentioned."**

i think its all about compiling views (or view directories). but im not figure it out yet.

consequently , if i move all my view files to same directory , this case never happens. but it will be very confusing and not feel right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
It's all about compiling views at starting the application (not at runtime).

And its speeding up your website (especially if you have too many views)

**Solution:**

1. Unload project
2. Right click on the unloaded project and go > "Edit *.csproj"
3. Paste these settings to bottom line of the file

   `<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
     <!-- Remove obj folder -->
     <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
     <!-- Remove bin folder -->
     <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseOutputPath)" />
   </Target>`
4. Reload the project
5. Paste this code to global asax > Application_Start

   ```
   var siteId = "1"; // you can find your own from applicationhost.config
   var appVirtualDir = $"/LM/W3SVC/{siteId}/ROOT";
   var clientBuildManager = new ClientBuildManager(appVirtualDir, null, null,
                               new ClientBuildManagerParameter
                               {
                                   PrecompilationFlags = PrecompilationFlags.Default,
                               });
   clientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication();
   ```
6. Run the project